# Return only values if pattern is matched in gsub

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a string containing bills in this form:

```
 bills <- c("2940 Green apples 250g", "5435 Bananas 0,5kg", "3425 Milk")
```

I want to extract the weight of the products and I did so with:

```
gsub(".*\\s(\\d*,*\\d+)\\s*(g|kg)$", "\\1", bills)
"250"       "0,5"       "3425 Milk"
```

This kind of works since it correctly returns 250 and 0,5 for the first two entries, but why does it return the whole third entry "3425 Milk"? I thought that by using `"\\1"` I would tell `gsub` to extract the first matching group, which here is `(\\d*,*\\d+)`. Therefore, I would expect the last entry being a `NA` or an empty string. Thus this is my expected output:

```
expected <- c("250", "0,5", NA) # OR
expected <- c("250", "0,5", "")
```

Comment: `gsub` only substitute matches and in this case `3425 Milk` hast no match, so it is not updated.

Comment: You could use `.*\\s(\\d*,*\\d+)\\s*(g|kg)$|.*`, but you'll get empty string instead of `NA`.

Comment: @markalex That makes sense. Updated question. If you post Ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add alteration to capture everything.

In case when your substitution string doesn't introduce new symbols (only recombination of captured groups, like `\\1` or `\\1\\3\\2` for example), this will result in replacing input string with empty one:

```r
gsub(".*\\s(\\d*,*\\d+)\\s*(g|kg)$|.*", "\\1", bills)
# [1] "250"  "0,5" ""
```

Also I'd change `,*` to `,?`, as I don't believe your input will be valid if it contains something like `1,,,5g`

Answer (score 1):

Using *stringr*, I'd keep "g" and "kg", because when removed these numbers are in different scales.

```
library(stringr)

bills <- c("2940 Green apples 250g", "5435 Bananas 0,5kg", "3425 Milk")

str_extract(bills, "\\d+(\\,\\d+)?(k?g)")
# [1] "250g"  "0,5kg" NA
```

Comment: That is nice, although I don't understand it yet.. Anyway, `I'd keep "g" and "kg"` --> I extract this in an extra strep, then having the weight and unit in two variables makes it possible to calculate all to g, for example. Thanks!